# Proving $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots, x_r] \subset \operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots, x_{r+1}]$

Tags: commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field. Is there an elegant proof of the fact that $\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots, x_r] \subset \operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots, x_{r+1}]$?

I proved it as follows: let $P \in \operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots, x_r]$ and take non-zero $f,g \in k[x_1,\cdots,x_{r+1}]$ such that $f g \in P$. If both $f, g \in k[x_1,\cdots, x_r] \cap k[x_1,\cdots, x_{r+1}]$, then $f \in P$ or $g \in P$ by hypothesis. If not, then $fg$ is a non-zero polynomial in $x_{r+1}$ with coefficients in $k[x_1,\cdots, x_r]$. But then $fg \in k[x_1,\cdots,x_r]$ (since $fg \in P$), contradiction.

Comment: Why is $k^r \subset k^{r+1}?$

Comment: jspecter, unfortunately this does not help. Manos, recall that the category of affine schemes is anti-equivalent to the category of rings. This is what Georges Elencwajg uses in his excellent answer below.

Comment: Hint: if $\phi :A \to B$ is a surjective ring homomrphism, then the associated map on spectrums $f: Y=Spec B \to X=Spec A$ is a homeomorphism of $Y$ onto a closed subset of $X.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most natural immersion you can get from your data is the one obtained from the surjective $k$-algebra morphism $$k[x_1,\cdots, x_{r+1}]\to  k[x_1,\cdots, x_r]  $$ sending $x_i\mapsto x_i$ for $i=1,...,r$ and $x_{r+1}\mapsto 0$.
This algebra morphism yields the closed immersion of $k$-schemes $$\operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots, x_r]=\mathbb A^r_k \hookrightarrow \operatorname{Spec} k[x_1,\cdots, x_{r+1}]=\mathbb A^{r+1}_k$$ which is just  the linear embeddding of $\mathbb A^{r}_k$ onto the hyperplane $x_{r+1}=0$ of $\mathbb A^{r+1}_k$
...and this is first year undergraduate linear algebra trying to  puff itself  up as  scheme theory!

Answer (score 2):

Is this elegant: $\mathfrak pR[X]\cap R=\mathfrak p$?